# Marshalling C type to C# for FMU dll method calling

Tags: c, pinvoke

I'm trying to call methods from unmanaged dll and I'm stucked.
For fmi2Type and fmi2Boolean I can use byte?
How callback functions (and pointer to them) should looks like in C#?

Method I'm trying to call is:

```cpp
fmi2Component fmi2Instantiate(fmi2String instanceName,
                    fmi2Type fmuType, 
                    fmi2String fmuGUID, 
                    fmi2String fmuResourceLocation, 
                    const fmi2CallbackFunctions* functions, 
                    fmi2Boolean visible, 
                    fmi2Boolean loggingOn)
```

Type descriptions are:

```cpp
typedef void*           fmi2Component;               /* Pointer to FMU instance       */
typedef void*           fmi2ComponentEnvironment;    /* Pointer to FMU environment    */
typedef void*           fmi2FMUstate;                /* Pointer to internal FMU state */
typedef unsigned int    fmi2ValueReference;
typedef double          fmi2Real   ;
typedef int             fmi2Integer;
typedef int             fmi2Boolean;
typedef char            fmi2Char;
typedef const fmi2Char* fmi2String;
typedef char            fmi2Byte;

typedef struct {
   const fmi2CallbackLogger         logger;
   const fmi2CallbackAllocateMemory allocateMemory;
   const fmi2CallbackFreeMemory     freeMemory;
   const fmi2StepFinished           stepFinished;
   const fmi2ComponentEnvironment   componentEnvironment;
} fmi2CallbackFunctions;

typedef enum {
    fmi2ModelExchange,
    fmi2CoSimulation
} fmi2Type;

typedef void      (*fmi2CallbackLogger)        (fmi2ComponentEnvironment,     fmi2String, fmi2Status, fmi2String, fmi2String, ...);
typedef void*     (*fmi2CallbackAllocateMemory)(size_t, size_t);
typedef void      (*fmi2CallbackFreeMemory)    (void*);
typedef void      (*fmi2StepFinished)          (fmi2ComponentEnvironment,     fmi2Status);
```

For callbacks I made callbacks containing class and delegates for each callback.

```cs
public class FMICallbackFunctions
{
    public delegate void FMILibrary_FMICallbackLogger(IntPtr fmiComponent, string instanceName, int status, string category, string message, IntPtr parameters);

    public delegate IntPtr FMILibrary_FMICallbackAllocateMemory(int numberOfObjects, int size);

    public delegate void FMILibrary_FMICallbackFreeMemory(IntPtr @object);

    public delegate void FMILibrary_FMIStepFinished(IntPtr fmiComponent, int status);

    public FMICallbackFunctions(FMILibrary_FMICallbackLogger logger, FMILibrary_FMICallbackAllocateMemory allocateMemory, FMILibrary_FMICallbackFreeMemory freeMemory, FMILibrary_FMIStepFinished stepFinished)
        : base()
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.allocateMemory = allocateMemory;
        this.freeMemory = freeMemory;
        this.stepFinished = stepFinished;
    }
}
```

Then initialize that class and trying to pass it to unmanaged method call

```cs
FMICallbackFunctions callbackFunctions = new FMICallbackFunctions(logger, allocateMemory, freeMemory, stepFinished);
```

but getting an error: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I think it cause of wrong callback parameters. Have anyone any hints what might be wrong?